# Want to create custom audio effect in native c/c++ for android

Tags: android-mediaplayer, soundtouch

I am working on project which deals with audio video playback in Android KitKat. I am able to play video using video view and it's MediaPlayer helps to modify the audio track of video. I know about Playbackparams which can be used for pitch and tempo shifting but it's available from API 23.

I heard about a library called Sound touch which can be used for pitch and tempo pitching but the source code available for the same shows that it works for WAV files.

I am interested in using sound touch library as a audio effect library which I can place in Android's /system/etc/audio_effects.conf and place the SO file in /system/lib.

But I don't know how to turn this sound touch library in order to make it read audio from Android MediaPlayer as I am planning to call this library in the same as we use presetreverb/equalizer?

Kindly help me out if anyone has done such an implementation.